# How to Throttle WiFi Connection

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, bandwidth, qos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to slow down my WiFi speed in Thomson Speedtouch](https://superuser.com/questions/463419/how-to-slow-down-my-wifi-speed-in-thomson-speedtouch)

I have a Thomson TG585 V7.
Many computers and smartphones are connected to my modem, and my Internet is limited, I can only download 5GB per month, so with so much people connected, youtube, facebook, they are spending my whole bandwidth, I can't change the password and disallow them from using my WiFi, my modem doesn't have any QoS settings, and I managed to block youtube using Parental Control, I actually made a redirect, but yet they use facebook and they want it...

I can throttle each PC individually, by using XP Traffic Shaper, but yet I cannot control iPhones and Samsung phones, I updated my modem's firmware hoping that I'll have some QoS settings but I didn't, I can't use aluminum on the antenna because they will see it, I just hope if there's a way to slow down my WiFi.

Comment: @techie007 did you notice that this duplicate is my question as well?

Comment: You're essentially asking the same question again. I can't really spot the difference — you are still asking for throttling traffic for iPhones and Samsung phones through your Thomson router. If your older question actually isn't fully answered, then please don't accept an answer on it. You could offer a bounty on the old question to draw attention. Otherwise, if this really is a *new* question, please [edit] it to the point where it becomes clear, and then `flag` for reopening. Thanks!

Comment: whoops. well, everytime I know how to answer a question, it's either a duplicate or offtopic. /badluck

Comment: Don't worry I gave you rating, even though it didn't help me, but at least you cared, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better solution!
You can simply ask them to use Opera (on desktop) and Opera Mobile/Mini on the phone.
(They have to enable "Opera Turbo" on both Opera desktop and Mobile. Mini uses a similar technology by default, which they/you can't even turn off.)

If they won't agree on the first (as they prefer something else), you can set up a "Compressing proxy". Similar to Opera's technology, it will compress everything down to your needs, and sent them to the client. It works as a HTTP(S) proxy.

There are two softwares that can do the job:

- Rabbit v4
- Ziproxy

Of course, you need a server for this. You can rent a cheap VPS from any VPS provider. You need at least 256 mb for Ziproxy, and 512 mb for RabbIT. (As the latter is written in Java.)

Comment: I know my question is not an answer to the question in title, but the situation itself. It would be too long for a comment.