# How can I monitor the network traffic/bandwidth on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

We currently have a crappy networking at our office, I meant that the router nor the switch cannot monitor the network. And we currently do not have any tool which can monitor this network.

So what I want to do is to monitor the network traffic of all the computers connected to this network. Something like I can see their transfer rates and things. I already tested a program called Net-Peekr, but the problem is that I need to install Net-Peeker Agents on all of the computers I want to monitor. It works fine but I cannot monitor the people who connects to our network via WiFI, because I don't have access (cannot install Agent) to those laptops or smartphones. Thats why I want a solution on which I won't have to install any agents on the PC's I want to monitor.

I saw a software long ago which does not have to use agents, which acts as a server. Like, the computer in which that software is installed needs another network card, and the switch is connected to this extra network card or so. I don't really understand that concept but if that's a solution, that's also fine.

Is it possible and what is the best solution for this?

Comment: Is all you want to monitor total network traffic?

Comment: The only thing I want to do is just see who is using how much traffic of my internet. Like the download and upload speed of each of the computers connected to my network. It will be good if I can limit the speed or cut out the connection for a specific PC. Something like Net-Peeker but without Agent installation.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the title  *best way to monitor* could lead to closing for *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: Sounds like you are taking the long way around solving your problem. Just get a DD-WRT router which can monitor your traffic. If your office is smallish something like a DIR-825 would work nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](http://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network), http://superuser.com/questions/94499/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-use-of-each-device-on-wifi-network

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are running into is that you want to do QoSish things without the tech to support it.
To straight monitor your wifi space, you could just have a spectrum analyzer running and then see when your wifi usage has increased based on the increased activity on the analyzer.

However, that does not seem like what you want. If you want to do granular monitoring on a per device basis, as well as a potential for QoS you either have to control the end user devices (using net-peeker for instance) or have that technology on your hardware (router/switch/ap).

If you hardware does not already support this you can try seeing if you can upgrade it using something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato).

Else, you can setup a computer to act as a gateway and install [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) on it. You can also install Linux and use one of the many tools with that. Windows is also an option although I don't know of tools for that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are searching for a solution like [this](http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/)?

**[SoftPerfect Bandwidth Manager](http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/)** is a full-featured traffic management tool for Windows. This can monitor and manage your traffic, and also can set rules and limits.