# Monitoring network usage across different devices on lan

Tags: networking, router, lan, monitoring

My internet connection has come with an upper limit on the usage after which it throttles the speed. They have provided me with a portal where they update my internet usage everyday but I have a feeling that it is not correct. I want to keep a check on the internet usage myself but I am unable to find a tool to help me do so. I have a router through which we use wired as well as some wireless devices including smart phones - both iphones and android as also windows and linux laptop. The router is a belkin router (model F7D2301 v1). I could not find any ddwrt firmware support for this model and also no other firmware that could help me. Can SNMP help? How do I find out if the router supports SNMP? Any other application using which I can monitor network bandwidth usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](http://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network), [How to monitor bandwidth use of each device on wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/94499/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-use-of-each-device-on-wifi-network)

Comment: These threads again mention using dd-wrt which in my case does not help since my router is not supported.