# Restrict/limit/monitor devices on WiFi network

Tags: wireless-networking, monitoring

I am not really sure where the best place to post this is so apologies if it isn't a good fit here.

I am trying to find a way to do any of the following:-

- Limit WiFi for specific devices on a WiFi network owned by myself.
- Monitor activity on specific devices on the same network without having to install apps on each device.
- Use various parental control features for specific devices on the same network without having to install apps on each device.

When I refer to 'devices, I mean handheld devices, so typically smartphones or tablets.

I am unsure whether anything exists which allows access to devices on a network over WiFi alone. I have full control over the network and all devices on it.

The reason for asking is I am after device specific access/control without the users of the devices being aware.

**Edit**

It is a small network, consists of 5 or 6 users on 5 or 6 different devices.

The fibre optic broadband is supplied by Virgin Media and the router is provided by them, the default [Super Hub 2AC](http://www.virginmediabusiness.co.uk/PageFiles/5537/SuperHub2ac_CustomerGuide.pdf). WLAN supporting dual concurrent band wireless 'n' at 2.4GHzand 5GHz and wireless "ac" at 5GHz. There are no other routers or switches in use on the network at present.

I don't have a network diagram as such but it is literally just broadband into property to router, and then router WiFi off to 5 or 6 wireless devices (Samsung Galaxy tablets, Samsung Galaxy phones, Apple iPhones and a couple of other Android/iOS devices also).

Typically, it is usually the same devices used by the same users, I'm just looking to identify them on the network and then control by device.

Comment: You don't mention which network devices (routers, switches, WAPs) you have. The configurations will vary by make and model.

Comment: Also, a network diagram would help.

Comment: You also don't mention size.  How many users?  How many access points? Do you need to control access by user?  Or just by device type?

Comment: Thanks for your queries, I have edited the question to include some details specific to your queries. I don't know if this can help get the question re-opened...?

Comment: Is this for a home network?

Comment: That is a consumer-grade device, and questions about those are specifically off-topic. You should ask this question on [su].

Comment: Yes, it is a home network. Thank you, I shall ask over at Super User.

Comment: Your requirements necessitate the need for another device to manage the network.  A router running DD-WRT/OpenWRT can provide the basic functionality you are looking for(access restrictions/parental controls/etc).  A more complicated/granular approach can be achieved with a dedicated hardware firewall and/or proxy like squid.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/94499/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-use-of-each-device-on-wifi-network