# Utility/Sniffer to track internet traffic/speed of all PCs in local network

Tags: sniffing

It doesn't matter if utility is for Ubuntu or for Windows XP/7, just need to see what pc is using the most traffic in local network.

Probably some spammer etc on that pc.

Need to get rid of that, before calling to my ISP.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a managed switch you can set a port to monitor traffic through the switch. Connect a PC to that port and run something like [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/news.php) or [etherape](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/) on that PC

See [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

Answer (score 0):

Try these first:

- Do you have access to the switch? Just have a look on the switch panel.
- Do you have access to the router? Take a look at the log/adjust loglevels

Mind you packet sniffing can be risky business, and it may or may not be legal for your situation. It is fairly unlikely you would be detected but you need *careful* firewlling.

To start with I guess you can start from Wireshark http://sourceforge.net/projects/wireshark/files/

Comment: It's my business network mate :D . Ofc i have an access to router and etc. But i'm not in the office right now, so i'll have to do it via teamviewer etc remotely. Logs is good tip, but should i parse them? It's a bit hard work to do.

Comment: Umm, I guess we can start with wireshark first.. Back then when I was still doing network admin as a side job of my high school days we really just look at the switch and see who's blinking too much =)...

Comment: Yea that's nice way to track the issue :D

Comment: Btw does Wireshark have graphs or something like that? Or overall packets sent/received by specific ip?

Comment: Ethereal was renamed Wireshark some years ago. Excellent tool.

Comment: Wireshark can easily generate these variable. Just set a filter. e.g. ip.src == 10.2.3.4, etc.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - I was recommending ethereal but soon after I write it I found out that it was renamed. showing my age =P