# Monitor and manage Internet bandwidth over my home network

Tags: windows, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

I have a small home network which is based on my ADSL router (ASUS WL-AM604g). All of the computers in my network are based on Windows 7. My computer is always on and connected to the Internet. Most of the time I want my computer to use all the bandwidth available on my network. I wanted to know if there is a software that I can use to see how much bandwidth each computer on my network is using and if possible sometimes limit its bandwidth. Thank you.