# Monitoring applications' network traffic

Tags: port, monitoring, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

Is there any software similar to [currports](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor/). Is these programs you can see which application is connecting to internet.

I'm considering my options about other programs with similar or more functionality. Showing bandwidth usage is a preference too.