# Monitor bandwidth on personal network

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

I have a personal Wifi network at my home used by the usual range of devices(laptop, desktop, smartphones etc.) I use a midrange Belkin router.
Sometimes the internet connectivity becomes simply too slow. I get a feeling as if some device is using too much bandwidth(maybe has a virus/trojan?) I am wondering if there is some software i can use to get a GUI view of all the devices on the network and the bandwidth each of the device is using? Maybe even see the process that is doing that? I am not too well versed in networking and am not looking for anything too complicated(read command line). Maybe something GUI Based? And all my machines are have Windows 7 in them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for something dead simple, I would suggest just installing the network monitoring widgets in windows 7.

http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=86656dc5-b0fe-489d-b115-44a76e050f63

This is not the best solution, but in terms of simplicity, can't get much easier than this.

Alternatively I would suggest getting a different router and installing DD-WRT on it.  In this scenario you can view a lot of network information directly on the router for all network devices.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. DD-WRT seems to be a great idea I was hoping for something which will get me a network wide info(without flashing the router)? Because i also have XBox, Smartphones connecting to the same network.