# Is there a program to know internet usage for each computer in a network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)
>   [Monitor bandwidth on personal network](https://superuser.com/questions/380484/monitor-bandwidth-on-personal-network)

I would like to know if there is a program which can, at the end of the day, tell us how much data was downloaded by a machine in a network?

I have both Windows 7 and Mac machines in my network. We use Wifi network in our office.

Please let me know.

Comment: Your router has to support this somehow, if you configure your router yourself (Firewall and NAT) this is possible. I don't know of a way that automagically works in every network.

Comment: And how do we configure it in a router. We have Belkin router.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor bandwidth on personal network](http://superuser.com/questions/380484/monitor-bandwidth-on-personal-network) and/or [How to monitor bandwidth use of each device on wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/22893/monitoring-bandwidth-across-multiple-systems-in-a-home-network) and/or [Monitoring Bandwidth Across Multiple Systems in a Home Network](http://superuser.com/questions/22893/monitoring-bandwidth-across-multiple-systems-in-a-home-network)

Comment: Also see [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](http://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

Comment: Messed up one of the links, it's [How to monitor bandwidth use of each device on wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/94499/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-use-of-each-device-on-wifi-network)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with your router if it's supported by the 3rd party firmware.

[TomatoUSB](http://tomatousb.org/) builds by [Toastman](http://www.4shared.com/dir/v1BuINP3/Toastman_Builds.html) and [Teaman](http://code.google.com/p/tomato-sdhc-vlan/) and also [Gargoyle Router](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/index.php) have per machine bandwidth monitoring.