# Monitoring Bandwidth Usage on a Wireless Network

Tags: skype, wireless-router, network-monitoring, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

Is there anyway for me to monitor my network bandwidth without installing firmware on my router? It includes wireless connections and I can't install any programs on the other laptops that use the net.
Also, an iPad is used for talking through Skype, I heard that Skype uses a lot of bandwidth and so want to be able to see how much. Is this possible on the iPad? 
I have a 30GB Bandwidth limit, so I have to see who is using alot of it.

Thanks in Advance,