# Virtualization and monitoring network traffic

Tags: networking, virtualization, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](https://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

I want to monitor all traffic coming from the virtual machine. I need to see http/https requests and stuff like that. Could you provide me best virtualization + monitoring software? I was thinking about vmware and fiddler (running on not-virtual os) What do you think about it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific. I was thinking about possibility to see all http/https requests and stuff like that.

Comment: what class of virtualization system are you looking to use (desktop or server) and what type of guest network connection (NAT/bridged/localonly/etc)? are you adverse to using a proxy?