# Individual Data usage monitoring

Tags: networking

We have one Airtel WiFi connection at our office. We have 5 laptops with wifi connection and 5 mobiles also. We have Airtel 4 ports wireless ADSL router make Beetel 450TC3. Everyday we are sure that bad colleagues are consuming data by downloading nonsense stuffs. How to check that who is using how much data in their laptops as well as mobiles. Is there any free software to which can be installed. Presently the broadband cable is inserted to the airtel router and from there 3 desktops are connected thru lan cable and 5 laptops with wifi connections.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty difficult to do this for free - After looking online, I expect your router is not capable of doing these things - which means you need another device to do it.

Because your clients are using WIFI its even harder.

You will need to find another piece of hardware which is capable of (at minimum) logging packets going through it - realistically you want something which can track usage per-ip.   You will find doing this tricky to do on a standard PC (although if you have a spare PC with at least 2 ports, a switch and Wireless network card you can probably cobble something together with Linux - but its by no means a straight-forward solution), so in practical terms, if you need to ask the question - No, there is no free software which can do this.

If you can acquire an ethernet router with WIFI on it that is capable of running DD-WRT, Tomato or Gargoyle, you can disable WIFI on the ADSL router and enable it on the Ethernet router - and plug the WAN port of the ethernet port into the LAN port of the ADSL router (and move any devices plugged into the LAN port of the ADSL router to the LAN ports of the Ethernet software), and configure DD-WRT to do handle this - better, you can use QoS to give these people lower service guarantees, letting them leach when there is bandwidth available but giving other users/sites priority.  [Look here](https://superuser.com/questions/243978/can-dd-wrt-or-tomato-keep-track-of-gb-usage-per-billing-period-per-device) for how to do this.