# How to measure the monthly total bandwidth use for an internet connection (OS independent)

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

I have 2 laptops and 2 smartphones which, when at home, use the home's WiFi Internet connection via a Belkin Wireless N+ 802.11n Router.
All these devices have different operating systems.

Is there a way I can measure the total bandwidth used each month for all uploads+downloads via that WiFi router, without having to install some app to do this on each device?

Edit: Router details as below:

- Firmware Version: 2.00.04 (Nov 12 2008 10:51:08)
- Boot Version: v0.05
- Hardware (Model No.?): Belkin Wireless N+ 802.11n - F5D8236-4 v2 (01)

Comment: You may want to include your exact router model number.

Comment: If your router supports DD-WRT firmware, it will keep very detailed reports on bandwidth usage.  Post the exact model # of your router.

Comment: @techie007 @bwall I added the WiFi router details in the question

Comment: Ok, that model of router is known to be incompatible with DD-WRT.  Doing it at the router is probably the only option that fits your criteria as stated above (OS independent).  You could buy a router that has this feature built-in (very few do), or buy a router that's compatible with DD-WRT.  Here's the list of routers that are supported by DD-WRT : http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices

Comment: @bwall Thanks :) Could you please post this as an answer so I could mark it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring Bandwidth Across Multiple Systems in a Home Network](http://superuser.com/questions/22893/monitoring-bandwidth-across-multiple-systems-in-a-home-network)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](http://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)

Answer (score 1):

Personal-home-consumer grade routers are not equipped with software to do this kind of thing, even if the underlying OS could do it. It's a shame, but the vast majority of potential customers really do not care about "advanced features" and the manufacturers care even less about spending money to develop unwanted features. This is reasonable.

If you wish to do things like traffic shaping, monitoring, unlimited NAT translations you'll have to get a "real OS" on your router. That can be done by installing a dedicated BOX (cheap pentium 500mhz or somesuch) between your router and switch with bsd or linux, or by putting dd-wrt on your "modem-switch-router". Buying an expensive router with advanced features is also possible.