# Which WiFi routers have the Quality of Service feature?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, qos

I read about monitoring and limiting bandwidth can be done on routers which have a Quality of Service feature, but which routers have this feature? Which would you recommend.

I read about the QoS here:
[Are there any wireless routers that allow bandwidth monitoring and throttling?](https://superuser.com/questions/260/are-there-any-wireless-routers-that-allow-bandwidth-monitoring-and-throttling)

I am working in an office where we all use a shared public wifi hotspot. At times the bandwidth is saturated and we would like to give preference to the paid tenants while still keeping the free wifi available to the public.

I suspect that someone (a new tenant) is downloading a lot of music via torrents which has made the wifi largely useless. I am looking to throttle that usage with a QoS router.

Comment: Would you recommend either of these routers?

Cisco WAP2000 Wireless G Access Point - 54Mbps, 802.11g, PoE, RangeBooster

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3680331&CatId=372

Linksys WRT54GL Wireless Router - 54Mbps, 802.11g, 4-Port, Open Source Linux Version

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1820385&CatId=2667

The first one states that it has QoS but the second might, but it is not mentioned. I am leaning toward the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Linksys wrt54g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) has QoS.  We have it hacked with the "tomato" firmware, but I think it has QoS capabilities even without the hack.  I heard that netgear will be coming out with QoS capable routers, but I don't know if they have them yet.  We've been happy with our linksys so far, but we are just using it at home with two people and six computers.

Comment: Strongly agree.  Using a WRT54GL with tomato firmware and it meets all my needs!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that nowadays any well-known brand has more than one router model with QoS.

Just browse their sites : Linksys/Cisco, D-link, Netgear and more.

There are also open-source firmware replacements for routers which include QoS featurs: [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) and [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).